# call function before tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: is called - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have set up a tableView in a ViewController. This table view has 1 section, 2 prototype cells: one is used to return the number of rows in section, the other one is used to display a custom header.

- In `viewDidAppear()`,  `self.loadData()` function is called to retrieve the data from NSUserDefaults. This data will be used in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`  to populate the labels in the header section. 
  The problem is that `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is automatically called before `viewDidAppear()` is called, as a consequence the labels in header section are not populated with the data retrieved from NSUserDefaults. 
  How can I call  `self.loadData()` before `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is called?

Comment: Use viewWillAppear

Comment: @Shades           If I use viewWillAppear   the .Checkmark  accessory no longer shows on to the row that was previously selected. I assign a checkmark based on the indexPath that is recorded in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: As @matt said, call tableView.reloadData() after loading your data so it populates with everything you retrieved.

Comment: It works if I use  tableView.reloadData() in viewDidAppear, I assume that the checkmarks could not be loaded in viewWillAppear because the view was not showing yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem — the data is not ready when the table view first appears. Simply give correct answers to the questions that the table view data source and delegate are asked, given the current state of things; if you have no data, say that there are no sections, for example. When you do have data, call `reloadData` on the table view to get the questions to be asked again.